# Pairs function issues

Tags: r, scatter-plot

I am trying to create a scatter plot for the first 10 columns of data. The first column is a list of "Yes" and "No". When I run the pairs function, it gives me the error "Error in pairs.default(college[, 1:10]) : non-numeric argument to 'pairs'". Any ideas on how to fix this? I am very new to R, so I have a very basic understanding of the program.[Link to the data I am using](https://sheet.zoho.com/sheet/officeapi/v1/ccd40a4abe62acc9c61faf35ff1ab7d7e4012be99e37d6222884a2389034223a29ba12f53569b504590f11a63a49cee38b61a29dd27080a8ee12730ed21c8edf)

I am able to run it no problem on columns 2 though 10.

See my code below:

```
setwd("C:/Users/judob/Desktop/Modern Statistics")
college=read.csv("college.csv")

fix(college) 
rownames(college)=college[ ,1]
fix(college)
college=college [,-1]
fix(college)

pairs(college[,1:10])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pairs()` function requires numeric columns of a matrix or data frame as input. However, your first column is not numeric but of character type. We can fix this easily:

```r
college[,1] = as.numeric(factor(college[,1]))
```

Now, `pairs(college[,1:10])` should work.